# Reorder objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

What is the best way to order and transform:

```
{
  '32': 'foo',
  '24': 'bar',
  '36': 'doe'
}
```

into:

```
[
  {'24': 'bar'},
  {'32': 'foo'},
  {'36': 'doe'}
]
```

I need to order them based on key, which is a string in the original object. jQuery’s API is allowed to use.

Comment: Those are 2 completely different objects.... one is an object with a few properties and the other is and array with a few object elements...

Comment: I added "transform" into the first sentence. It’s basically the same data, but I need an array that can be looped in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function arrayMe(obj){
    var indexes = [];
    for(index in obj){
        indexes.push(index);
    }
    indexes.sort();
    var return_array = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++){
        return_array[i] = {};
        return_array[i][indexes[i]] = obj[indexes[i]];
    }
    return return_array;
}
```

All you would have to do is:

```
arrayMe(oldObject);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/uBqjt/